# How to seam a cricket ball and control which way it turns?

Tags: cricket

I have recently been introduced to the wobble seam delivery and was wondering whether there was a delivery out there that lets the bowler control which way it turns without sacrificing speed. I am aware of leg cutter and off cutter, but these are slower deliveries meant for suprise.

I remember reading an article about a "three-quarter seam" delivery used by Tim Southee but cant really understand how it works.

Is it even possible to control the direction of turn of the ball with a seam delivery without reducing the speed of the ball?